# Mapping a hostname to an IP address on Android | Resolve local hostname/domain on Android

Tags: ip, hostname

I have a requirement of "map a hostname to an IP address on Android" programmatically. This may require an entry in /system/etc/hosts file. I can see few open-source code that edit the /system/etc/hosts file but require Root Access.

Can I achieve same functionality without Root Access?
or 
please suggest any alternate solution to resolve local host/domain.

Thanks

Comment: Editing of /system/etc/hosts file is not permissible without root access. However, in order to map a hostname to an IP, you can setup your own DNS server on your network and configure the device to use that network.

Comment: @nandal thank you very much for your response. Can you please elaborate your answer more? I mean to setup own DNS server and configure device with it.